# CWBCO1049 - The IBM i server application is not started, or the connection was blocked by a firewall (Communication error occurred)

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, uwp, db2

we developed a UWP app, here we use Xamarin Forms for UI, for API we used ASP.net and use the IBM DB2 for Database and host the API in the IIS server.

This exception was thrown only in the Production Environment, not in the Test environment. I don't know what causes this issue. In the Test environment, We continuously check and run the module in which the exception was thrown. But the exception was not replicated. I don't know how to solve this exception. Done a lot of searches on Google. But I didn't get the answer.

This exception has been thrown around for a long time.
If anyone knows the solution, please share it. Thanks in advance :)

```
----------------------------------------
Timestamp: 8/20/2022 8:21:35 PM

Message: HandlingInstanceID: cc5775ce-32b7-4840-9b9c-56027b4c18e0
An exception of type 'IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2CommErrorException' occurred and was caught.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
08/20/2022 16:21:35
Type : IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2CommErrorException, IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9cdb2ebfb1f93a26
Message : A communication error occurred.
Source : DDRAPIDataAccess
Help link : 
Errors : IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2ErrorCollection
MessageDetails : CWBCO1049 - The IBM i server application  is not started, or the connection was blocked by a firewall
MessageCode : 10061
SqlState : 
ErrorCode : -2147467259
Data : System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
TargetSite : DDRDataAccess.DDRBO.AlertDetails getPopupAlertDetails(Int32, System.String, System.String, System.String)
HResult : -2147467259
Stack Trace :    at DDRDataAccess.DDRAPI.AlertsDAL.getPopupAlertDetails(Int32 UserID, String SCID, String v_date, String v_time) in D:\DDRAPI\AlertsDAL.cs:line 281
   at DDRAPI.Controllers.AlertController.GetUserPopupAlerts(Int32 UserID, String SCID, String date, String time) in D:\Controllers\AlertController.cs:line 100

Additional Info:

MachineName : WIN-SEI******I
TimeStamp : 8/20/2022 8:21:35 PM
FullName : Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
AppDomainName : /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-133054308451942484
ThreadIdentity : 
WindowsIdentity : WIN-SEI******I\Administrator


Category: LoggingDDRAPI

Priority: 0

EventId: 100

Severity: Error

Title:Enterprise Library Exception Handling

Machine: WIN-SEI******I

App Domain: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-133**********484

ProcessId: 125712

Process Name: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe

Thread Name: 

Win32 ThreadId:23796

Extended Properties: 
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: On the machine running the app, is the specified TCPIP port-number for i-series opened in the firewall, for both inbound and outbound TCP traffic ?

Comment: Please make sure `The IBM i server application` has started and you also can disable firewall for test. If the issue still occurs, pls check the eventviewer.